# WPF ItemsPanelTemplate wont allow to add a simple UIElement

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Im trying to style Items control and have this XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DatatemplatePlateItemContainer">

    <Grid x:Name="PlateItemContainer">

        <!-- Does recursive ItemTemplate selection        -->
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}"
                        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateselectorPlateItem}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=GridRow}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=GridColumn}"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!-- This line will not let the ItemsControl to load -->
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

If I try to add any UIElement (Rectangle in this sample) inside its ItemsPanelTemplate.Grid - line 7 from the bottom - it fails. Just commenting out that  - and it works. What can be wrong with this simple XAML? It wont give much info - only this in the output, that I can not trace:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterException' occurred in System.Xaml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.
```

Comment: Your XAML is invalid. ItemsPanel cannot have hard-coded children. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to have rectangles at each side of the grid, to detect mouse drag over each rectangle - and detect the drop logic - to the left or to the right/top/bottm of current Item

Comment: so change `ItemsControl.Template`